# Get all children and grandchildren from either of the two parent columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find all the parent-children relationships, which are all linked to my primary column `ID`

[image]

[image]

I have tried the below thus far, but that works with only one column.

```
    WITH tb  (id,Name, Level, Path, Parent)
AS
(
 SELECT 
    id,Name, 1 AS Level, 
    CAST('/'+Name as nvarchar(max)) as Path,
    CAST(NULL as nvarchar(max)) as Parent
 FROM krishtest
 WHERE parent1 IS NULL

 UNION All

 SELECT 
    e.id,e.Name, x.Level + 1 AS Level, x.Path + '/' + e.Name as Path,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(x.[Path]) ,0 , CHARINDEX( '/', REVERSE(x.[Path])) )) as [Parent]
 FROM krishtest e
 JOIN tb x ON x.id = e.parent1


)
SELECT Name, Level, Path, Parent FROM tb
```

Comment: What's the logic in having a parent2 to begin with?

Comment: @Ultimater same as parent1. Either parent1 or parent 2 will have the details [probably a parent3 or 4 in the future]. So I need to create the output based on that. .

Comment: If you have the choice, you should change this into two tables.  The first would have just the ID and Name columns.  The second would have two columns, ChildID and ParentID, with one row per relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i understand the parent can be in either parent1 or parent 2 column; then in such case your query should be as below

The only change is use of keyword **[COALSECE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/coalesce-transact-sql)** which takes the first non NULL value from the list.

**bug assumption is that both parent1 and parent2 are not (Non-Null) together.**

<kbd>**[See live demo](http://rextester.com/AMJB38575)**</kbd>

```
;
WITH tb  (id,Name, Level, Path, Parent)
AS
(
 SELECT 
    id,Name, 1 AS Level, 
    CAST('/'+Name as nvarchar(max)) as Path,
    CAST(NULL as nvarchar(max)) as Parent
 FROM krishtest
 WHERE COALESCE(parent1,parent2) IS NULL

 UNION All

 SELECT 
    e.id,e.Name, x.Level + 1 AS Level, x.Path + '/' + e.Name as Path,
    REVERSE(SUBSTRING( REVERSE(x.[Path]) ,0 , CHARINDEX( '/', REVERSE(x.[Path])) )) as [Parent]
 FROM krishtest e
 JOIN tb x ON x.id = COALESCE(e.parent1,e.parent2)


)
SELECT Name, Level, Path, Parent FROM tb
```

Comment: @KrishOnline This sort of editing a question after accepting an answer is generally frowned upon in SO. You should definitely ask a new question based on your edits. [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions] Chameleon questions don't really help solve the purpose of asking help on SO

Comment: @KrishOnline Your question originally was to about selection and now it states a different problem altogether. I'd definitely attempt to answer it if you post a new question

Comment: Cool. will do it